# Reverse proxy through Nginx tomcat for GeoServer, but cannot visit MapPreviewPage and DemoPage

Tags: ssl, proxy, geoserver

my nginx config:

```
location /geoserver/ {                      
    proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header x-forwarded-proto https;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;   
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver/;        
}
```

when visit **https**://mydomain/geoserver/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.demo.MapPreviewPage?0
then the url will change to **http**://mydomain/geoserver/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.demo.MapPreviewPage?0

how can i solve that